# Django migrations deployment strategy with AWS ECS Fargate?

Tags: django, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate, django-migrations

What is the recommended deployment strategy for running database migrations with ECS Fargate?

I could update the container command to run migrations before starting the gunicorn server. But this can result in concurrent migrations executing at the same time if more than one instance is provisioned.

I also have to consider the fact that images are already running. If I figure out how to run migrations before the new images are up and running, I have to consider the fact that the old images are still running on old code and may potentially break or cause strange data-corruption side effects.

I was thinking of creating a new ECS::TaskDefinition. Have that run a one-off migration script that runs the migrations. Then the container closes. And I update all of the other TaskDefinitions to have a DependsOn for it, so that they wont start until it finishes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I could update the container command to run migrations before starting the gunicorn server. But this can result in concurrent migrations executing at the same time if more than one instance is provisioned.

That is one possible solution. To avoid the concurrency issue you would have to add some sort of distributed locking in your container script to grab a lock from DynamoDB or something before running migrations. I've seen it done this way.

Another option I would propose is running your Django migrations from an AWS CodeBuild task. You could either trigger it manually before deployments, or automatically before a deployment as part of a larger CI/CD deployment pipeline. That way you would at least not have to worry about more than one running at a time.

> I also have to consider the fact that images are already running. If I figure out how to run migrations before the new images are up and running, I have to consider the fact that the old images are still running on old code and may potentially break or cause strange data-corruption side effects.

That's a problem with every database migration in every system that has ever been created. If you are very worried about it you would have to do [blue-green deployments with separate databases](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/blue-green-deployments-overview.html) to avoid this issue. Or you could just accept some down-time during deployments by configuring ECS to stop all old tasks before starting new ones.

> I was thinking of creating a new ECS::TaskDefinition. Have that run a one-off migration script that runs the migrations. Then the container closes. And I update all of the other TaskDefinitions to have a DependsOn for it, so that they wont start until it finishes.

This is a good idea, but I'm not aware of any way to set `DependsOn` for separate tasks. The only `DependsOn` setting I'm aware of in ECS is for multiple containers in a single task.