# Run DB Migration by one task only in AWS ECS

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, gitlab, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I'm hosting my Laravel application on AWS ECS, I have one Service and 4 tasks are running.

How I can run the DB migrations by only one task, once I deploy.

Thank you

Comment: This question was asked about Django here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75406805/django-migrations-deployment-strategy-with-aws-ecs-fargate but it really amounts to orchestrating DB migration during ECS deployments with any framework, not just Django or Laravel. Please see my answer there.

Comment: Thank you Mark, so what do you suggest to me as a best practice please

Comment: What is "best" is entirely subjective. I'm not going to tell you what the **one best practice** is, because there isn't one.  You need to determine what is best for your situation.